# How do I code a minecraft CLIENT/mod with python, instead of java?

Tags: python, minecraft

I want to code a custom client for minecraft with python.

I want to be able to change the text of some menu buttons in the game 'minecraft'.

I don't want to use java, but python. Again, I get how to make a minecraft SERVER with python, but I wan't to make a client. How can I do this, if it is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minecraft is developed in Java so, if you want to edit the code to create a custom client you should do it in Java, if you want explicitly use Python you can call a script from Python to Java.

Here are some ways you can achieve this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-working-with-python

If you only want to change the menu buttons here is a tutorial you can follow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPN3-lQP-Y0&ab_channel=GreatOrator